# Product searcher on backend

Tags: module, magento-1, backend, catalogsearch, development

I'm developing a backend module, which displays a table with all the products. I'm trying to make a searcher in order to search an specific product from the table. It's like making an order from the backend, that you have to choose some products and you can make filters with the searcher.

I tried to make it in php and javascript, but by the moment it doesn't works as I would like. So now I'm trying to do it in Ajax, but I've never typed any code in ajax, so it will take me a few hours to learn the basics.

The fact is, if any of you know where's the .phtml code which let you make orders from the backend, because I want to know how magento does the searcher. Maybe If I copy the code, it will be easier. Or if anyone knows a better way to do it, please let me know it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do it with generic adminhtml grid?

Comment: there is a product_chooser_widget you can use with AJAX: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Widget_Chooser and Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Widget_Chooser_Container

Comment: @Tim what do you mean? The div where is the table is called like: `<div id="order-items_grid" class="grid">` and the table has this class: `<table class="data order-tables" cellspacing="0">` but I don't know how to implement the searcher

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt how can I implement this widget? Could you give me a little bit more of information about implementing the widget? Where does it go? How can I call it? Thanks.

Comment: @inavas how exactly are you adding a table into backend?

Comment: @Tim I've created a custom module, where in the controller, I add a .phtml ( `$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('x.phtml'); $this->_addContent($block);` ). So in that x.phtml I've the table (and other things).

Answer (score 4):

This should help you to add a Product Chooser widget in your custom module.

http://andreitara.com/2012/02/using-magento-product-chooser-widget-in-youre-own-module/

The author have also uploaded this extension on Github! Just download it as an extension and I think you will be good to go.

https://github.com/andrei-tara/magento-product-selector